# Bootstrap 4 to have navbar items allways expanded on small screen with no button

Tags: navbar, nav, twitter-bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

I am working on a website footer, and am looking for a way to make a nav that has all it's items in one row on a large screen, and collapsed to many rows on a smaller screen. The collapsing happens just fine, but I cannot figure out a way to:

a) automatically show the rows and not have them hidden until the toggle button is hit

b) eliminate the toggle button all together

My current code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-xl py-0" id="footerBar">
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">link1</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link2</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

Currently, this just collapses into nothing without a button (obviously because I have removed it). Is there an easy way to make it default to expanded on smaller screens?

Comment: Works as it should for me. (Using IE mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...

Needed the "show" class applied to the collapse (the div with id `navbarColor03`).

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-xl py-0" id="footerBar">
 <div class="collapse navbar-collapse show" id="navbarColor03">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#" target="_blank">link1</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">link2</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```